# V or XLOOKUP a 4 digit number from the last 4 characters of a range of 12 digit numbers

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Sheet 1 column A has Names and Column B has 12 Digit ID Numbers.

Sheet 2 has a single column full of the last 4 numbers of random employees ID's.

I need to X or Vlookup Sheet 2 to match those last 4 numbers with full 12 digit ID numbers. If there are many matches, I would like to list them out.

Here is what I have but it Produces a #N/A error:

```
=XLOOKUP(Sheet2!$A$1,Sheet1!$B$1:$B$900,Sheet1!$A$1:$A$100)
```

I can't find a way to only search the last four digits of each of the range cells in Sheet1 (the range of 12 digit ID's). Please help.

Sample Data:

Sheet 1

| Name | 12 Digit ID |
| --- | --- |
| John | sample111TypoHere1344 |
| Jake | 123456782567 |
| Eliza | 558456782567 |
| Tony | 558456789911 |
| Jane | 564231846155 |

Sheet 2

| Last Digit ID's | Guess for Employee's Full ID From Searching Sheet 1 |
| --- | --- |
| 2567 |  |
| 9911 |  |
| 4555 |  |
| 1234 |  |

Expected output:

Sheet 2

| Last Digit ID's | Guess for Employee's Full ID From Searching Sheet 1 |
| --- | --- |
| 2567 | Jake or Eliza |
| 9911 | Tony |
| 4555 | Typed wrong or Does Not Exist |
| 1234 | Typed wrong or Does Not Exist |

Comment: `=XLOOKUP("*"&Sheet2!$A$1,...`

Comment: Sample data will prove to be very valuable here.

Comment: Probably could use `FILTER` if you want to return multiple matches.

Comment: @JvdV how do I submit sample data?

Comment: @Excellerator, you could use markdown sample data. See [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support) meta post on the matter. It will make it easy for readers to starts working on your problem. I usually use a [generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) to make quick work of it.

Comment: For Multiple Records Extraction Using `FILTER()` is better & best as @BigBen Sir mentioned, !

Comment: @ScottCraner you're fast! That produces a #N/A error though. Even though everything is set as a "Number"

Comment: @Excellerator instead could you upload a `MOCK` data screenshot by editing the post so that it helps for all of us!

Comment: Try `=XLOOKUP("*"&Sheet2!$A$1,Sheet1!$B$1:$B$900&"",...`

Comment: @ScottCraner Sir, wild card match mode 2 as well

Comment: yup I missed that. 
 As @MayukhBhattacharya stated `=XLOOKUP("*"&Sheet2!$A$1,Sheet1!$B$1:$B$900&"",Sheet1!$A$1:$A$100,,2)`

Comment: Perfect! It would be even better if you include your desired results. Do you want a comma seperated list for say '2567' or does it need to spill to the right?

Comment: @Excellerator you need `FILTER()` Function only here as mentioned already by @BigBen Sir, since there are multiple matches

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya unfortunately I only have the last 4 digits to figure out who an employee could be. Narrowing down the list to employees whose last 4 digits match is the goal

Comment: It would also help to add an extra column which only contains the last 4 digits of the id. =RIGHT("Your 12 Digits ID Columns";4)

Comment: @JvdV thank you! I added tables using your recommendations

Comment: @ScottCraner, you correctly answered my other question. If you submit your answer I will mark it as the answer, you genius!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right, a lot of hints towards `FILTER()`, and looking at your data I do think the following should work:

[image]

Formula in `E2`:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",,FILTER(A$2:A$6,--RIGHT(B$2:B$6,4)=D2,"Nothing"))
```

The double unary is there since I kind of expect the 12-digit ID's to be text.

Comment: I ran this on my data and got a #VALUE! error. Do you have any advice? Thank you for the help

Comment: The error seems to arise when the "12 Last Digit ID" column has some of the values set as "Text" and some as "Number." Is there a way to force the filter to convert all data it fetches to text or all to number for the comparison?

Comment: As mentioned above, the double unary is meant to deal with both text or numbers. In case any other leading characters other than numbers are present this will result in an error. However, looking at your sample data that isn't the case @Excellerator

Comment: I added a sample typo to my sample data up there that causes the #VALUE! error. It doesn't need to correct typos, just skip over them and still resolve

Comment: I submitted this as a separate question as it appears to be unrelated to the logic in your formula and marked your answer as the answer. It is not fully answered yet though, please help with this error if you can here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71562250/filter-through-array-of-text-and-numbers-in-excel

Answer (score 3):

You might use a VLookup(), based on a helper column, based on the simple formula `=MOD(A2,10000)` as a way to get the last four digits of a number.

Here an explanation in a screenshot:

[image]

The `VLookup()` formula is the following:

```
=VLOOKUP(D2,$B$2:$C$3,2)
```

Comment: I'm afraid `VLOOKUP()` won't be able to retrieve multiple records to join together. The idea of an helper is always a good one!

Answer (score 2):

### EDIT

You may try this as well, after **[JvdV](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9758194/jvdv)** Sir's advice, Sir, I have made some corrections to my earlier formula. Though **[JvdV](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9758194/jvdv)** Sir's provided formula is absolutely perfect & I shall personally follow the same.

• Formula used in cell **E2**

```
=TEXTJOIN(" or ",,FILTER($A$2:$A$6,
D2=--REPLACE($B$2:$B$6,1,LEN($B$2:$B$6)-4,""),
"Typed wrong or Does Not Exist"))
```

[image: FORMULA_SOLUTION]

Comment: I don't think that's entirely correct. It seems to me OP is looking to match the last 4 digits. Not anywhere before those. This could lead to false positives. I'd rewrite this to something like `=TEXTJOIN(", ",,FILTER(A$2:A$6,ISNUMBER(SEARCH("????????"&D2,B$2:B$6)),"Nothing"))` when we would apply the ranges as per the other answer.